# ImportError: No module named '_catboost'

Tags: python, machine-learning, importerror, catboost

I am using python 3.4 and have installed catboost library but when i try to import, it shows the following error.

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python34\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in <module>()
 17 try:
---> 18     from _catboost import _PoolBase, _CatBoostBase, CatboostError, 
_cv, _set_logger, _reset_logger
 19 except ImportError:

ImportError: No module named '_catboost'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-f6570a454eaf> in <module>()
----> 1 from catboost import CatBoostClassifier,cv, Pool

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\catboost\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .core import Pool, CatBoost, CatBoostClassifier, 
CatBoostRegressor, CatboostError, cv  # noqa
  2 try:
  3     from .widget import CatboostIpythonWidget  # noqa
  4 except:
  5     pass

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in <module>()
 18     from _catboost import _PoolBase, _CatBoostBase, CatboostError, _cv, 
_set_logger, _reset_logger
 19 except ImportError:
---> 20     from ._catboost import _PoolBase, _CatBoostBase, CatboostError, 
_cv, _set_logger, _reset_logger
 21 
 22 from contextlib import contextmanager

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: How did you install `catboost`? with `pip install catboost`?

Comment: Yes i did `pip install catboost`

Answer (score 4):

you may

!pip3 install catboost

and then

from catboost import CatBoostClassifier

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using python 3.x you need to use

```
pip3 install catboost
```

not

```
pip install catboost
```

Comment: I tried uninstalling and then again installed using `pip3 install catboost`

 from ._catboost import _PoolBase, _CatBoostBase, CatboostError, _cv, _set_logger, _reset_logger
     21 
     22 from contextlib import contextmanager

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: can you post the full traceback as an edit to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall cleanly and re-install catboost again. I fix that error by this.

Answer (score 0):

catboost module is present in python package index version 3(pip3).so try to install it 
pip3 install catboost (either in ubuntu terminal or python terminal).
it worked for me!!